# Ошибка при подключении к bybit v5

Tags: php, curl

Подскажите что не так было сделано и почему выдает ошибку и что это за ошибка?

Документация с параметрами

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/intro#parameters-for-authenticated-endpoints

Баланс

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/account/wallet-balance

Делал по инструкции

https://github.com/bybit-exchange/api-usage-examples/blob/master/legacy_demo/api_demo/futures/Encryption.php

```
$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'https://api.bybit.com/v5/account/wallet-balance';
$params['accountType'] = 'CONTRACT';
$params['timestamp'] = time() * 1000;
$params['api_key'] = 'публичный ключ';
ksort($params);

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(http_build_query($params)), 'секретный ключ');
$query = http_build_query($params) .'&sign='. $signature;

$url .= '?'. $query;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Bybit API)');

$output = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($output);
```

Выдает такую ошибку

**HTTP/2 404 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 content-length: 0 date: Thu, 06 Apr 2023 16:22:03 GMT traceid: 3fba21f858b54da54148cdce23ed8a2d timenow: 1680798123059 server: Openresty x-cache: Error from cloudfront via: 1.1 3fcabc15a7f22952dcacfedd3d2b6a14.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) x-amz-cf-pop: HEL50-C2 x-amz-cf-id: 7iYWiogbv-Bj4hH7tIOurD8FrxZukf2HIPspnkeuZMf_JsrbVjKt_A==**

Comment: считаю, по последней ссылке кривой пример. Параметры вернее передавать через CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972211/url-encode-with-curl-php. Также стоит заголовками прописать тип передаваемого контента и тип получаемого контента, наподобие как тут в вопросе (Content-Type и Accept) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850856/curl-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-php

Comment: но вообще 404 означает несуществующий урл, видимо $url неверной составил.